# iOS 9.3 apple music account country

Tags: ios, apple-music

According to https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/apple-music-best-practices-for-app-developers/

"Developers can see which country the users account is based"

I am unable to find any information on how I can do this. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

OK so SKCloudServiceController

```
requestStorefrontIdentifierWithCompletionHandler
```

returns a storefrontIdentifier that you can then map that to a country code using the mapping in https://github.com/bendodson/storefront-assistant/blob/master/StorefrontCountries.plist